# Return sets of keywords derived from fields in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Im kinda new to this i need help, i looked online couldnt find any answer im looking for. Basically, what im trying to do is for autocomplete based on keywords derived from some textfields

Given an example of my indices:

```
"name": "One liter of Chocolate Milk"
"name": "Milo Milk 250g"
"name": "HiLow low fat milk"
"name": "Yoghurt strawberry"
"name": "Milk Nutrisoy"
```

So when i type in "mi", im expecting to get the results like:

```
"milk"
"milo"
"milo milk"
"chocolate milk" 
etc
```

Very good example is this aliexpress.com autocomplete

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems like a good use case for the [`shingle` token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-shingle-tokenfilter.html)

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/your_index -d '{
  "settings": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "my_shingles": {
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "shingles"
            ]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "shingles": {
            "type": "shingle",
            "min_shingle_size": 2,
            "max_shingle_size": 2,
            "output_unigrams": true
          }
        }
      }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "your_type": {
      "properties": {
        "field": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "my_shingles"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

If you analyze `Milo Milk 250g` with this analyzer, you'll get the following tokens:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/your_index/_analyze?analyzer=my_shingles&pretty' -d 'Milo Milk 250g'

{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "milo",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 4,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 0
  }, {
    "token" : "milo milk",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 9,
    "type" : "shingle",
    "position" : 0
  }, {
    "token" : "milk",
    "start_offset" : 5,
    "end_offset" : 9,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "milk 250g",
    "start_offset" : 5,
    "end_offset" : 14,
    "type" : "shingle",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "250g",
    "start_offset" : 10,
    "end_offset" : 14,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 2
  } ]
}
```

So when searching for `mi`, you'll get the following tokens:

- milo
- milo milk
- milk
- milk 250g

Comment: This is exactly what im looking for- Thank u

Comment: are u able to help me with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064501/sort-by-sub-aggregration-count-elasticsearch