# sort by sub aggregration count elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi I have the following query

```
 "aggregations": {
      "catalogid-and-terms": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "catalog_id",
            "size":3,
            "order": {
               "keywords>_count": "desc"  <-- HERE IS THE PROBLEM
            }
         },
         "aggregations": {
            "keywords": {
               "terms": {
                  "field": "keywords",
                  "size":1,
                  "order": {
                     "_count": "desc"
                  },
                  "include": {
                     "pattern": "mi.*"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
```

So im trying to get the top keywords in a catalog however i want to sort by number of count of that keywords. how do i do that?

Comment: You have to realize that each term in the top aggregation might contain several terms in the sub aggregation even if `size: 1` is specified. I'm afraid this is not possible.

Comment: thanks for the comment, is there any work around? my objective is to get top keyword count in each store and sort by top keyword count